# Android: Listview with button Alternative

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm new to Stackoverflow & Android.

Referring to the title, I'm trying to make a list view with buttons.

I have researched and searching for tutorials and I see that many tutorials are using custom textview and button in XML layout.

What I want to know is:

Is it possible to do that just using list view and button directly instead of custom `TextView` and button?

I hope you understand what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want your button to anything related to the data in your listview? If so, you need a custom adapter. If your button just does the same thing regardless of the data, then yes, you can do that with a standard listivew and adapter. Just use a custom listview item layout that includes your button.

Comment: Each listview will contain an english phrase and it's translation. The button click will play the pronunciation of the related phrase. So, data in listview and button come from the same table in the database. I guess I have to use  the custom adapter then?